# Filtering rows using PREVIOUSMONTH

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure that filters rows and returns just the rows from the previous month (so as we are currently in August, return the rows from July).

This is the measure I have at the moment:

```
Prior months decisions made = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(table_name), 
    PREVIOUSMONTH('DIM - Date'[date_worked])
)
```

(for privacy reasons, I have not included the name of the main table)

Both the DIM - Date table and main table have a 'date_worked' column which I have used to link the two together when merging the queries.

The problem I am having is that the above measure just keeps returning the full data set rather than just the previous months data (July's data). Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Is your Dim Date table marked as a date table?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It wasn't marked as a date table but I have done this now and it hasn't made any difference (i.e. still returning the full data set rather than just the data from the previous month - July)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your measure code is fine. But to reflect your expectation, These below are the requirements-

**1.** You should have a separate date table like "dim_date" with column "date".

**2.** Your fact table "Table" will have a date column as well like "date_worked"

**3.** The relation between table "dim_date" and "Table" should have a 1 to many relation using columns dim_date[date] and Table[date_worked]

**4.** Now, create a Year slicer using column dim_date[Date].[Year]

**5.** Now, create a Month slicer using column dim_date[Date].[Month]

**6.** Now, create your measure as below-

```
Prior months decisions made = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Table), 
    PREVIOUSMONTH(dim_dates[Date])
)
```

You should have expected output now.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added a month and year slicer but when selecting a month on the slicer, the measure is still returning the full data set rather than just the data from the previous month

Comment: Your slicer is generating from a complete separate table?

Comment: You're a hero! This worked thank you so much. Still getting to grips with Power Bi!

Comment: you are most welcome. Nice to see that it worked and helped :)

Answer (score 2):

according to https://dax.guide/previousmonth/
the result is the previous month in relation to the first dates in input. and it only returns dates which are in your "DIM - Date"

maybe it is because your data is not filtered on the date "DIM - Date" table. If you input the whole date table, it will return the whole table.

The function doesn't know that we are in august, it determines the previous month based on your input.

try and add a month slicer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added a month slicer but when selecting a month on the slicer, the measure is still returning the full data set rather than just the data from the previous month